# Cloudera package version meaning

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I was going through the cloudera package component details. In the versioning detail, I could not understand what is the last number added to the version information by cloudera.

Example : [LINK](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_vd_cdh_package_tarball_55.html#concept_twe_rnn_yk)

**Component**        **Package Version**

Apache Avro     avro-1.7.6+cdh5.5.4+**118**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Last number in the Package Version is the number of Commits. You can find the Commits in the Changes File section in the Table.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my doubt.
I found in the file saying the branch is taken from "OLD_CDH_BRANCH : 'cdh5_5.6.x'". So does it mean that it's cut from 5.6.<previous_version> and commits are made to that.

Answer (score 1):

Any cloudera component comes with 3 different numbers i.e., base_version+cloudera_version+patch_level

**Example:** Apache Avro avro-1.7.6+cdh5.5.4+118

`base_version` is the version of the open-source component included in the Cloudera package.

`cloudera_version` is the version of the Cloudera package.

`patch_level` is the number of source commits applied on top of the base version forked from the Apache Avro branch. Note that the number of commits does not indicate the number of functional changes or bug fixes in the release. For example, a commit can be used to amend a version number or make other non-functional changes.